# preg_replace if a condition match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

While parsing a webpage, my parser stop due to invalid DOM structure. I want to fix it by replacing certain node.

I found there is an extra `</div>` which causing the parser stopped.

I need to write a regex which will check:
if any `</div>` followed by a `</div>` [i.e. no starting `<div>` tag in between. It will check  `<div` as the tag may have id or class to follow], then the last `</div>` will be replaced by `<div></div>`.

i.e. if `</div>` followed by a `</div>`, then last one will be replaced to `<div></div>`.

Thanks in advance.

example:
`<div>
  <img src="/lexus-share/images/spacer.gif" width="2" height="15" border="0" alt="">
</div> 
  <a href="http://www.somedomain.com"><img src="/pub-share/images.jpg"></a> 
</div>`

Comment: Can you A: Provide some code with your attempt and B: Clarify what exactly you want?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit that into your question :)

Comment: So you want something to check that every `<div>` has a `</div>`?

Comment: if no `<div` found between two `</div>`, then the last one will be replaced with `<div></div>`. Thats what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This only works if there are no nested `<div>`s (not sure if they are legal):

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '%</div>       # Match a closing div tag
    (              # Match and capture in group 1...
     (?:           # ...the following regex:
      (?!</?div>)  # Match (unless a div tag intervenes)
      .            # any character.
     )*            # Repeat any number of times.
    )              # End of capturing group
    (?=</div>)     # Assert that a closing div tag follows%six', 
    '</div><div>\1', $subject);
```

This changes

```
<div> <img src="/lexus-share/images/spacer.gif" width="2" height="15" border="0" alt=""> </div> <a href="http://www.somedomain.com"><img src="/pub-share/images.jpg"></a> </div>
```

into

```
<div> <img src="/lexus-share/images/spacer.gif" width="2" height="15" border="0" alt=""> </div><div> <a href="http://www.somedomain.com"><img src="/pub-share/images.jpg"></a> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is you try a different approach for this rather than using regex as it will not be easy to make it work with nested  tags.

I don't know what language you are using to parse the document, but the code logic that you could write is:

Parse through the whole document searching for the string `div>` and make 2 variables to count openingDivs and closingDivs.

If character before `div>` is `<`,
openingDivs++.

If character before `div>` is `/`, closingDivs++ and check `if (closingDivs > openingDivs)`

If the condition ever becomes true, you can make the program output the position of the div or replace the `</div>` with blank space or null.

Hope this helps. :)